# How for loop in Python work?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
Sentence = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'dea', 'eab', 'abc']
Words = list()
iterations = 0
a = 0

for word in Sentence:
    Words.append(0)
    for nextWord in Sentence:
        if(word == nextWord):
            Words[iterations] += 1
            Sentence.remove(nextWord)
            a +=1
    iterations += 1
```

I expect that both for loops will load all elements from *Sentence*, so at the end of this loops will be *Sentence* empty. But it is not, *Sentence* after this code looks like this: ['bcd', 'dea']. Please, can you explain why?

I would be grateful if you could recommend me some improvement of this code.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your aim here?

Comment: You're trying to modify `Sentence` while iterating over its elements.  Don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate through a list in Python, any modifications to the list you are iterating through will have an effect on the for loop. For example, take this code:

```
my_list = list()
my_list.append("hello")
for element in my_list:
    my_list.append("hello")
```

This code will run forever, because my_list keeps growing in size.

With your code, you have to think about what is happening inside the for loop.

There are two instances of 'abc' in your list, so after the first iteration, where the first element in the list is checked, they are both removed from Sentence. This leaves a list that looks like this

```
['bcd', 'cde', 'dea', 'eab']
```

Now, Python checks the second element in the list. This is where the issue is caused. Python skips over the 'bcd' element and moves straight on to 'cde', removing 'cde' from Sentence, leaving a list that looks like this:

```
['bcd', 'dea', 'eab']
```

Now, Python checks the 3rd element in the list, which is 'eab' and then removes it from the list, and then Python knows that there are no more elements in Sentence to iterate through because it has reached the end and the for loop breaks, leaving Sentence like this

```
['bcd', 'dea']
```

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want your code to do in the end so I can't really propose a solution but I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of `Sentence` is `'abc'`.
The inner loop removes `'abc'` from `Sentence`, leaving `['bcd', 'cde', 'dea', 'eab']`.

The outer loop continues with the second element of `Sentence`, which is now `'cde'`.
The inner loop removes `'cde'`, leaving `['bcd', 'dea', 'eab']`.

The outer loop continues with the third element of `Sentence`, which is now `'eab'`.
The inner loop removes `'eab'`, leaving `['bcd', 'dea']`.

The outer loop now wants to continue with the fourth element, but `Sentence` only has two elements so it stops.

The moral of this story is, don't modify a collection while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a for loop in python, it creates an iterator on the object on which you are looping. In this case the object is `Sentence`

The below code demonstrates what happens if the list is modified

```
Sentence = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'dea', 'eab', 'abc']

sentence_iterator = iter(Sentence)

print(sentence_iterator.__next__()) # This will print 'abc'

Sentence.remove('abc')  # This will modify the list to ['bcd', 'cde', 'dea', 'eab', 'abc']

# This below code will print 'cde' not 'bcd' as the list is modified.
# and the sentence_iterator has already seen the first element
print(sentence_iterator.__next__())
```